# Is it possible to get your detection risk below 3?

Tags: payday-2

I currently have most of the Ghost perks.  When carrying the CAR-4, the Bernetti 9, and wearing a two-piece suit, my detection risk is 3.

No matter what mods I put on my weapons, though, I can't seem to get my detection to go any lower.

**Is 3 visibility the cap, or could I get it lower with more stealthy equipment?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.** 3 detection risk seems to be a hard limit. Even with maximized concealment (fully modded Mosconi 12G, modded Compact-5, and Two-Piece suit) and the Ghost perks, your detection risk still comes out to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The lowest I've had is from fists, concealment modded Raven, Micro Uzi, Suit, and of course the concealment skills. Was still 3. (Raven - 28 conc, Micro Uzi 30 (31 possible, going for it but I doubt it makes a difference), fists and suit are of course 31 and 32.)

Answer (score -1):

I once saw someone with 2 and they weren't labeled a hacker. They told me it was in one of the dlc's that had stuff that made them below 3.

Comment: It's possible, since this game has an ever-growing amount of DLC. But it would be good if someone can edit this to say *which* equipment would give you a 2 rating.